Swagger-ui from springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui display wrong data, But online swagger editor is correct
My openapi.yaml file showing correct data in editor, but not in my local project, any idea what could be the problem here?
Image from my project swagger-ui
enter image description here
Image from swagger editor
enter image description here
Im using springboot 3, springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui (2.5.0) with openapi-generator-maven-plugin (7.6.0)
i tried diffrent versions of springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui and openapi-generator-maven-plugin but it does not make any diffrence, i also tried to find any similar question, no luck
